# Insertar por lote registros txt a MySQL con JAVA

Tags: java, batch

Estoy trabajando en JAVA y necesito guardar registros que estan en un archivo.txt a mi base de datos MySQL, el problema es que son muchos registros e insertarlos uno a uno demora mucho tiempo.
Necesito saber como aplicar los métodos `addBatch` y `executeBatch` en el siguiente código

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;

public class BD { 
private String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private String cadenaConexion="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1/log";
private String usuario="root";
private String contraseña=""; 
public BD(){
    try {
        Class.forName(driver);//cargar el driver que se ha creado 
        con=DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion,usuario,contraseña);
        System.out.println("Conectado con BD");
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("No se ha podido establercer una conexion");

    }   

}

private PreparedStatement psInsertar;
private Statement st;
private Connection con;

public void insertar (Datos d) throws SQLException {
st=con.createStatement();
psInsertar = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO  LOG_PG509 (fecha,hora,milisegundo,secuencia,banco,suscriptor,codrespmov,tiempo_total,tiempo_pic,tiempo_movilnet,servicio,detalle_excepcion)"+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
psInsertar.setString(1, d.getfecha());
psInsertar.setString(2, d.gethora());
psInsertar.setString(3, d.getmilisegundo());
psInsertar.setString(4, d.getsecuencia());
psInsertar.setString(5, d.getbanco());
psInsertar.setString(6, d.getsuscriptor());
psInsertar.setString(7, d.getcodrespmov());
psInsertar.setString(8, d.gettiempo_total());
psInsertar.setString(9, d.gettiempo_pic());
psInsertar.setString(10, d.gettiempo_movilnet());
psInsertar.setString(11, d.getservicio());
psInsertar.setString(12, d.getdetalle_excepcion());
psInsertar.executeUpdate();
}
}
```

El código mostrado anteriormente realiza la conexión satisfactoriamente con la base de datos.

Gracias

Comment: Veo que ya tienes unas cuantas preguntas hechas, pero no has aceptado ninguna respuesta como válida. Por favor, revisa el [tour] para ver como se hace.

Answer (score 1):

Modificando tu método `insertar` para que reciba una lista de `Datos`

```
public void insertar (List<Datos> lista) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "INSERT INTO  LOG_PG509 (fecha,hora,milisegundo,secuencia,banco,suscriptor,codrespmov,tiempo_total,tiempo_pic,tiempo_movilnet,servicio,detalle_excepcion)"+ "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (Datos d : lista){
        psInsertar.setString(1, d.getfecha());
        psInsertar.setString(2, d.gethora());
        psInsertar.setString(3, d.getmilisegundo());
        psInsertar.setString(4, d.getsecuencia());
        psInsertar.setString(5, d.getbanco());
        psInsertar.setString(6, d.getsuscriptor());
        psInsertar.setString(7, d.getcodrespmov());
        psInsertar.setString(8, d.gettiempo_total());
        psInsertar.setString(9, d.gettiempo_pic());
        psInsertar.setString(10, d.gettiempo_movilnet());
        psInsertar.setString(11, d.getservicio());
        psInsertar.setString(12, d.getdetalle_excepcion());

        ps.addBatch();
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
}
```

[Fuente](https://viralpatel.net/blogs/batch-insert-in-java-jdbc/)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Coloque lo que me sugeriste y me genera un error en `Datos` porque Datos no es una variable sino una clase dentro del proyecto

Comment: ¿Que error te genera? Estoy tratando Datos como una clase.

Comment: Me dice "Datos cannot be resolved to a variable" y "d cannot be resolved to a variable"

Comment: ¿Que version de java usas?

Comment: Java 8.0.1110.14

Comment: Vale, es que es for en vez de foreach. Me lie. Lo he editado.

Comment: Ok! ya se quito el error que generaba, pero ahora en otra de mis clases me aparece otro error, copio parte del código de la clase donde me aparece el nuevo error

Comment: Datos d1 =new Datos(fecha,hora,milisegundo,secuencia,banco,suscriptor,codrespmov,tiempo_total,tiempo_pic,tiempo_movilnet,servicio,detalle_excepcion);
                    BD bd = new BD();
                    bd.insertar(d1);

Comment: el error lo genera en bd.insertar(d1), dice "The method insertar(List<Datos>) in the type BD is not applicable for the arguments (Datos)"

Comment: Es que eso lo tienes que cambiar, antes pasabas un objeto y ahora tienes que pasar toda la lista.

Comment: ya le pase toda la lista y al ejecutarlo me dice "Datos cannot be cast to java.util.List"

Comment: Si te dice eso es que no le has pasado la lista.

Comment: lo coloque de esta manera  `bd.insertar((List<Datos>) d1);`

Comment: Eso es un cast, no puedes castear un objeto Datos a una Lista.

Comment: entonces como pasaría la lista completa ?

Comment: Tienes que pasar todos los objetos Datos dentro de una implementación de List como puede ser ArrayList